# How do I get dynamic properties from OkObjectResult

Tags: c#, anonymous-class

I return `IActionResult` with the value of an anonymous object from a controller method.
How do I get the data out again?

Here is the controller method reduced to the very problem:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    long size = file.Length;
    return Ok(new { count = 1, size });
}
```

Then I get the `.Value` property, which is an `object` and make it `dynamic`.
But no, it is not recognised.

```
[Fact]
public async Task UploadFileTest()
{
    //  #   Given.
    var formFile = new Mock<IFormFile>();
    var sut = new HomeController(null);

    //  #   When.
    IActionResult result = await sut.UploadFile(formFile.Object);

    //  #   Then.
    OkObjectResult okResult = (OkObjectResult)result; // Ok.
    dynamic dynValue = okResult.Value; // Ok.
    var count = dynValue.count; // Not ok.
}
```

Expected result:

`count` should be 1.

Actual result:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException : 'object' does not contain a definition for 'count'

Comment: Did you tried like this => `dynamic dynValue = okResult.Value as dynamic;` ? **OR** `dynamic dynValue = okResult.Value as ExpandoObject;` ?

Comment: @er-sho Trying to cast `dynValue` to `dynamic` won't do anything as it is already declared as a `dynamic`. So when trying to cast to `ExpandoObject` all that happens is that `dynValue` becomes null. `dynamic` and `ExpandoObject` are not the same thing. Plus for trying though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try reflection:

```
var count = (int)okResult.Value.GetType().GetProperty("count").GetValue(okResult.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your test and original code not in the same project, If that so, you need to create `AssemblyInfo.cs` in your original code project to make it (original) share the dynamic object structure.

you could see more at https://sodocumentation.net/csharp/topic/4264/assemblyinfo-cs-examples#-internalsvisibleto-

It shall has code like below (Replaced the string as your test name)

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyAssembly.UnitTests")]
```